# Ada GNAT.Serial_Communications behavior on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, ada

I have an Ada program that communicates with an Intellibox Basic(a box that allows you to control trains) that is connected via USB.

Under Windows, I had to install a specific Serial driver (CP210x USB to UART Bridge VCP). With that driver I can communicate perfectly with the box. That means sending commands to the box.

Under Linux I'm communicating via `/dev/ttyusb0` and I'm able to get messages from the box, but I can't send commands to the box. Nothing happens. I don't get an error or something.

Is the behavior of GNAT.SerialCommunication differently on Linux ? The program is the same. Do I have to setup certain things to get it to work on Linux ?

For example: A typical 2-byte command has the Command as the first Byte and the CRC check as the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble with Serial_Communication at some point, where it turned out to be a problem with hardware-handshake being enabled in Linux. It's hard-coded in g-sercom.adb, look for "CRTSCTS". If your Intellibox does not use hardware handshake, Write() will block.

I believe I solved it by removing the CRTSCTS mask from the flags.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. Still can't send messages to the IB. Do I have to install the driver mentioned above ?